# "Invalid command 'php_value'" in .htaccess for WordPress site after switching hosts

Tags: htaccess, wordpress

I moved my site which was on 00webhost to a new host. I set everything up but a 500 internal error shows up.

The error log reports the following:

> [Sun Feb 11 23:43:59.139864 2018] [core:alert] [pid 549884:tid 140054322136832] [client 77.75.78.164:60560] /home/dotcomwo/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

What should I do to get it working?

Comment: It would help to post the contents of that .htaccess file here.   Please edit your question and include the portions of it with the `php_value` in them.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite probable you've moved from a host where PHP was installed as an Apache module and is now configured as CGI/FastCGI. Instead of using `php_value` in `.htaccess`, you'll need to [set these values in a .user.ini file](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) instead. The format is the same as `php.ini`. (Some hosts also allow a *local* `php.ini` as well.)

The `.user.ini` file (note the dot prefix) goes in the document root of your site, just like `.htaccess`, but contains just the settings that relate to PHP.

For example, if you previously had something like the following in `.htaccess`:

```
# Include a PHP file on every request
php_value auto_prepend_file /home/dotcomwo/public_html/includes/config.inc.php
```

Then you would write this like the following in a `.user.ini` file:

```
; Include a PHP file on every request
auto_prepend_file="/home/dotcomwo/public_html/includes/config.inc.php"
```